# How to save xml file into xml column

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2008

I have an xml file I want to save it's content into database to read it again.

I use `XmlDocument` to load the xml file and using `InnerXml` to save this xml.

This is my code

```
cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO pages(BPMNID,XML) VALUES (@BPMNID,@XML)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BPMNID",2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@XML", XDoc.InnerXml);

cmd.Connection = conn;
conn.Open();

try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

When run the previous code I get an exception

> XML parsing :Unable to Switch the encoding

Hint: Xml column is a `xml` column

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Load the XML from the file into a **string** and then pass that into the SQL query. The SQL query doesn't know about `XmlDocument`:..

Comment: @marc_s I try to make that and give me the same exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use code like this:

```
public void SaveXml(int id, string xmlFileName)
{
    // read your XML
    string xmlContent = File.ReadAllText(xmlFileName);

    // set up query
    string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO pages(BPMNID, XML) VALUES (@BPMNID, @XML)";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(-your-connection-string-here-))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn))
    {
        // define parameters
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BPMNID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@XML", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1).Value = xmlContent;

        // open connection, execute query, close connection
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you mean `ReadAllText` ? not `LoadAllText`

Comment: I get the same exception

Comment: @Ahmed: updated my code - using `SqlDbType.VarChar, -1` seems to be working (at least for me), even with XML files containing the `encoding="utf-8"` in their header

Comment: Done, Thanks for your help